# PHP Clone the row from database but NULL is getting empty result

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a facebook style share post system using php and mysql.

I want to clone the following screenshot row from data:
https://prnt.sc/hhp97n

[image]

In this row you can see `post_hashtags` is *`NULL`* that means that post not have hashtag.
When i share this post i am getting this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/hhp8rx

[image]

I am not getting *`NULL`* for `post_hashtags` after the clone row.

It should be like this after the clone row: https://image.prntscr.com/image/Z5nloIeBSta6KCDCQfinqA.png

[image]

I'm not sure the way I'm going is true, but it works. I tried this with the following codes.

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->db,
  "SELECT post_id, post_text, post_title 
   FROM posts 
   WHERE post_id = '$post_id'") 
  or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
$data=mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

$post_title = isset($data['post_title']) ? $data['post_title'] : NULL; 
$post_text = isset($data['post_text']) ? $data['post_text'] : NULL; 
$post_hashtags = isset($data['post_hashtags']) ? $data['post_hashtags'] : NULL; 

$CloneThePost = mysqli_query($this->db,
  "INSERT INTO `posts`(post_title,post_text,post_hashtags)
   VALUES('$post_title','$post_text','$post_hashtags')"
  ) or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

Comment: This looks like a mess, please don't go on like this. There is no check against SQL vulnerabilities which will definitly put you in trouble! Also, there is a difference between inserting an empty string (which you do by using '$post_hashtags') and NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert a NULL, then you need to insert NULL. You are inserting a blank string: ''. You would have ssen this if you had printed the INSERT statement. You may previously have worked with Oracle database - for that DBMS a blank string is the same thing as NULL, but most DBMS treat them differently.

Its also worth noting that the duplication introduces an SQL injection vulnerability even if the original post capture is immune.

While you could do this:

```
$post_title = isset($data['post_title']) ? 
     "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $data['post_title']) . "'" 
     : NULL; 
$post_text = isset($data['post_text']) ? 
     "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $data['post_text']) . "'"
      : NULL; 
$post_hashtags = isset($data['post_hashtags']) ? 
     "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $data['post_hashtags']) . "'"
     : NULL; 
...
    VALUES($post_title,$post_text,$post_hashtags)
```

Personally I'd just try this...

```
INSERT INTO posts b (b.post_text, b.post_title, b.post_hashtags)
SELECT a.post_id, a.post_text, a.post_title, '" 
.  mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $post_hashtags) . "'
FROM posts a
WHERE a.post_id = '$post_id'
```

Although I'd be more tempted to normalize the schema.

Comment: After some experimentation I've confirmed your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try following code you have to set DEFAULT VALUE of field 'post_hashtags' as NULL in your table structure
```

$post_hashtags = !empty($data['post_hashtags']) ?$data['post_hashtags'] : NULL;

```
    if(!empty($post_hashtags))
    {
      $query="INSERT INTO `posts`(post_title,post_text,post_hashtags)VALUES('$post_title','$post_text','$post_hashtags')"
    }
    else
    {
        $query="INSERT INTO `posts`(post_title,post_text)VALUES('$post_title','$post_text')"
    }

$CloneThePost = mysqli_query($this->db,$query) or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

Comment: still tryed this same problem i have seen.